# Disable rails from embedding background images into CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have some fonts with @font-face and background images into my custom.css.scss file.
When I precompile assets for Heroku, I get a production css larger than 10MB which slows my website down to a crawl. Upon further inspection I discovered that the images and fonts are base64 encoded within the generated production css file. How do I disable this?

Some code from custom.css.scss:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSansCondensedLight';
    src: asset-data-url('opensans-condlight.eot');
    src: asset-data-url('opensans-condlight.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         asset-data-url('opensans-condlight.woff') format('woff'),
         asset-data-url('opensans-condlight.ttf') format('truetype'),
         asset-data-url('opensans-condlight.svg') format('svg');
        font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

becomes in production CSS file:

```
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSansCondensedLight';
    src: url(data:application/vnd.ms-fontobject;base64,nM8BALTOAQABAAIAAAAAAAILAwYDBQQCAgQBACwB...
    src: url(data:application/vnd.ms-fontobject;base64,nM8BALTOAQABAAIAAAAAAAILAwYDBQQCAgQBACwB...
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal; }
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say you have some fonts and backgrounds in your SCSS? Could you post your includes?

Comment: Yep, some code would be good :)

Comment: Have you tried "asset-url('opensans-condlight.eot');" instead of "asset-data-url"?

Comment: @RichPeck: Yes that gives me missing files on Heroku. It looks for the original file not the precompiled one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use `asset-data-url` sass will inline your assets as base64 data. that's the whole point.

you need to use `asset-path($relative-asset-path, $asset-class)` or similar methods to reference the asset from your css file: https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#features

if that does not work on heroku, make sure to check all the configurations: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Comment: Yep I figured that out. It 's just none of the helpers seems to work with heroku. I ended up putting the original images in the public folder.